# Counting determinants

Tags: determinant

> **Q.** Consider the set $\mathbb A$ of all determinants of order $3$ with entries $0$ or $1$ only. Let $\mathbb B$ be the subset of $\mathbb A$ consisting of all determinants with value $1$ and $\mathbb C$ be the subset of $\mathbb A$ of all the determinants with value $-1$. Choose the correct option:
>
> $(a)$ $\mathbb C$ is empty.
>
> $(b)$ $\mathbb B$ has as many elements as $\mathbb C$
>
> $(c)$ $\mathbb {A=B \cup C}$
>
> $(d)$ $\mathbb B$ has twice as many elements as $\mathbb C$

One way could be to list down all the determinants and count, which is the only thing I could think of. But what if instead of order $3$ we have order $n$?

Also, what is a general way to tackle such problems?

Comment: What are your answers and thoughts to the statements (a)-(d) ? Not all of them are true.

Comment: For example, can you find a matrix with determinant $-1$?

Comment: @daw, sorry, the question asks for one correct option out of the four.

Comment: I repeat: can you find an example with determinant $-1$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Yes... Sorry for the late response

Comment: Good. So, can you eliminate one of the four choices? Next question: can you find an example with determinant 2?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, so option a is fired... Yes found out one with determinant 2..

Comment: OK, so that eliminates another choice, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes. option c...

Comment: Good. So, we're left with b and d. They contradict each other, so they can't both be true, right? Now, do you know of an operation that will turn  $+1$ matrices into  $-1$, and at the same time turn  $-1$ matrices into  $+1$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Simply negating them ?? (for odd order square matrices)

Comment: Well, but we want to keep all the entries 0 or 1, so negating won't do.